# Why cant I use my c# classes in aspx.cs files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

My c# class code (Class1.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Montajat.App_Code
{
    public class Class1
    {

    }
}
```

default.aspx.cs code:

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I use Class1 in Page_Load of my aspx.cs file and why can`t I use it at the moment ?

Comment: possibly you need add `using Montajat.App_Code;`

Comment: You should be able to instantiate & use objects of any type in any aspx page's code-behind, so long as the class is known to the aspx project and you include the proper `using` statements.

Comment: @Grundy already tried this, didn`t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on top include **namespace**:

```
using Montajat.App_Code;

public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Class1 objClass1 = new Class1();
    }
}
```

or you can do it using fully qualified name:

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Montajat.App_Code.Class1 objClass1 = new Montajat.App_Code.Class1();
    }
}
```

your class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Montajat.App_Code
{
    public class Class1
    {
      public Class1()
      {

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) namespace 'App_Code' does not exist in the namespace 'Montajat'

Comment: 2) Class1 could not be found

Comment: just remove the namespace from Class1 and check

Comment: and put the class in root directory of project where aspx.cs is place

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     var objClass1 = new Montajat.App_Code.Class1();
    }
}
```

Does this works? Maybe you are missing the namespace?

Also, verify that your website has a reference to the project where you class is located. If you are not in the same project, you need to have a dll reference to the one that contain your class.

Comment: I am in the same project, I cant add Montajat.App_Code in using. it is not declared.